# Running Python 3 Turtle programs in the browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, skulpt, pyodide

I need to run some Python 3 programs that use Turtle Graphics. I was trying to display these on the browser. I found 2 options

- skulpt (https://skulpt.org). This does not seem to support Python 3 fully.
- pyodide. This uses Python 3 but does not seem to have packages for Turtle.

Is it possible to either use skulpt with Python 3 or is there a Pyodide package for Turtle?

Thanks

Comment: as I know all methods which can run Python in browser never support all modules.  Better forget it.

Comment: Which package are you talking about ? There's a [PythonTurtle](https://pypi.org/project/PythonTurtle/#description) as well as the [native lib in cpython](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)